# How to solve error regarding jquery in Rails-3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting one issue while some jquery script links are executing in Rails application.html.erb file.Actually i am trying to  open calender while user will click on text field using one third party jquery library. After the page loading it is not happening like that and no rails error but in console option i am getting the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createPlugin' of undefined
```

I think the above error due to page is not finding the appropriate script files given via links in application.html.erb but by using simple HTML and JS it is working properly.

Some of my codes are given below.

## application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MakeCalender</title>
  <link href="/assets/jquery.datepick.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="/assets/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/assets/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
 <script src="/assets/common.js"></script>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<% if flash[:color]=="valid" %>
    <div class="flash-message">
      <div class="container container_12 clearfix">
        <div class="grid_12">
          <p><%=flash[:notice]%></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% elsif flash[:color]== "invalid"%>
    <div class="flash-message">
      <div class="container container_12 clearfix">
        <div class="grid_12">
          <p><%=flash[:alert]%></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% else %>
    <div class="flash-message">
      <div class="container container_12 clearfix">
        <div class="grid_12">
          <p><%=flash[:notice]%></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

## views/calenders/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :calenders,:url => {:action => 'create'} do |f| %>
Enter Your Date :<%= f.text_field :date_today,placeholder:"Please enter your date",:id => "popupDatepicker" %>
<%=  f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

## javascript/common.js

```
$(function() {
    console.log('datepick');
    $('#popupDatepicker').datepick();
});
```

Please help me to resolve this issue after checking the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include core jquery library at the top before using any other jQuery plugin or library. Please follow below sequence to include your jQuery library in your code -

```
<!--This should be on top of any other jquery library or plugin-->
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Include rest of your plugins-->
<script src="/assets/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
 <script src="/assets/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
 <script src="/assets/common.js"></script>
```